# Construct an empty matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a class

```
class A
{
    int *const e;
    const int row, column;
public:
    A(int r, int c); // create a empty matrix with r rows and c columns passed in method
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A test(2,2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Question is how can I write a constructor that create a matrix which I can use ?

Comment: if you want any prebuilt matrix functionality look into libraries like Eigen

Comment: But in this project I dont want to use any library

Comment: `memset` is your friend, assuming you really just want an "empty" (which, BTW, has no real meaning in software development) matrix. Also, since the word `empty` appears in your question title, but not in the body, I have no idea what you're really asking for.

Comment: Also, stop using parameter names like `r` and `c`. I would either a) not hire you fresh out of school, or b) fire your ass after a few successive code reviews revealing that variable naming was not your forte'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sound like: 
How to save parameters into the constant row/column properties.

```
A::A(int r, int c): row(r), column(c), e(new int[r*c])
{
    for (int i=0; i<r*c; i++) e[i]=0;
}
```

Also do not forgot the destructor:

```
virtual ~A(){ delete[] e; };
```

In the parameter-list of the constructor, parameters are initialized in declaration order, so you cannot use row/column (they are not already initialized).

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor would just be

```
A::A(int r, int c) : row{r}, column{c}
{
    e = new int[r * c];
}
```

Then your destructor should be

```
A::~A()
{
    delete[] e;
}
```

And you can access the elements as

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << e[i * row + j] << " ";  // Using array arithmetic
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2758: 'A::e' : a member of reference type must be initialized
So should I first initialized variable first ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a pointer to a pointer to create a [normal] 2-dimensional array 
so

```
int ** const e;
```

Then the constructor can work like:

```
e = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int**) * a);
for(int i=0;i<a;++i) {
  e[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * b);
}
```

Your next problem is "how to initialize the constants". For this, you can refer to the answer here:
[how to initialize const member variable in a class C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class-c)

to implement this, put the inittializer code in a function:

```
initConstArray(const int** const a, int r, int  c) {
    e = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int**) * a);
    for(int i=0;i<r;++i) {
      e[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*) * b);
      for(int j = 0;j < c; ++j) {
        e[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
```

and call this function from the constructor initializer list:

```
A(int **a, int r, int c) : initConstArray(a, r, c) {
}
```

Comment: malloc? I may consider to use hard-coded pointer instead of smart pointers, but that is too deprecated for me.

Comment: Excuse my code. It is just here for the conceptual explanation. - Thanks

Comment: Just joking :-) but yes, there is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to implement the matrix with templates:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t ROW, std::size_t COLUMN>
class A
{
    std::array<int, ROW*COLUMN> a;
public:
    A():a(){};
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<3,3> test; 
    //test.printSize();
    //std::cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

Much shorter and cleaner.

To make commented lines to work, you must add to the class the following 2 functions:

```
void printSize(){ std::cout << ROW << "x" << COLUMN << std::endl; };

friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, A<R,C> mat){
    int col_count = 0;
    for (auto id=mat.a.begin(); id!=mat.a.end(); id++){
        os << *id << (++col_count%C==0?"\n":" ");
    }

    return os;
};
```