# How can we init structure members only once and make sure they are not mutable?

Tags: c++, initialization, structure, constants

I have a structure whose members should be inited only when the structure is constructed the first time. So, I can create a constructor and set the values appropriately. How can I make sure they are not mutable ? If I declare the members as const, I am not able to update them during construction.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class-c

Answer (score 1):

`const` is just what you need here. You *can* initialize your members in the constructor but you'll need to do it through a member initialization list :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : z(5) {}
private:
    const int z;
};
```