# Making parent class members unmodifiable for each derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor

I'm wondering how can I make unmodifiable a parent class member which will be different for each derived class.

My code now assigns its value correctly (depending on the Child class that calls the parent class' constructor), but `m_type` can be easily modified (in `myfunction`, for example) and that's what I'd like to avoid.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Piece_type{    king=1,     queen=3,    rook=3,     bishop=4,   knight=5,   pawn=6};

class Piece
{
    protected:
        Piece_type  m_type; // static Piece_type m_type; <- doesn't work

        Piece(Piece_type ex): m_type(ex) {}
};

class Pawn: public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn():Piece(pawn) {}   // To initialise m_type as pawn for all my Pawn objects

    void myfunction()
    {
        std::cout<<"My piece type is "<< m_type<<std::endl;;
        m_type= knight;   // This is the assignation I want to avoid happening
        std::cout<<"My new piece type i "<<m_type<<std::endl;
    }    
};
```

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class-c), but inheritance doesn't seem to make possible to declare a static variable and define its value through a member initializer.

I've found how to call the parent/base class constructor from the Child class in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120876/c-superclass-constructor-calling-rules).

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

---

**Edit**

I've slightly modified it so that not to confuse anyone, because `const` does work where I said it didn't.

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with "unmodifiable".

Comment: Do you absolutely need this behavior to be validated at compile-time, or are runtime checks acceptable here?

Comment: Why can't you make `m_type` `const`?

Comment: And why are you trying to express the piece type through both the `m_type` member and the `Pawn` class? Why do you need both?

Comment: @user2357112  "error: assignment of read-only member 'Piece::m_type' "

I have to admit that I have no answer to your second question..

Comment: @Eduardo: That error is **exactly what you asked for**. If you *don't* want an error when you try to modify the thing you want to be unmodifiable, what *do* you want?

Comment: Beware that const members prevent assignment operators from being generated.

Comment: omg... you absolutely right, @user2357112, I may stop coding for a few hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you didn't fall into the usual mistake of trying to use `const` member variables without a member initializer list, so `const` is all you need really:

```
class Piece
{
protected:
    Piece_type const m_type;

    Piece(Piece_type ex) : m_type(ex) { }
};

class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn() : Piece(pawn) { }

    void myfunction()
    {
        // m_type = knight; // Compile-time error
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 3):

They only ways to prevent a derived type from modifying it's parent's members is to make those members `private` or `const`. Since you can't make the member `const` the only other way would be to declare the member `private` and adding a `protected` accessor method such as :

```
Piece_type get_type() const 
{
    return m_type;
}
```

This way, derived classes can call `get_type()` to know `m_type`'s value but can't access it directly, preventing them from writing to it.

Comment: It seems that `const` finally works, but thank you anyway, I'll take that into account!