# why can I initialize a const member variable inside class definition

Tags: c++

I read a lot of answers saying that one must initialize a const class member using initializing list.
e.g. [how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class)
But why my code compiles and runs correctly?

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass()
    {
        printf("Constructed %f\n", value);
    }
    ~myClass()
    {
        printf("Destructed %f\n", value);
    }

    const double value = 0.2;
};

void test(const std::shared_ptr<myClass> &ptr)
{

    std::cout << "in test function" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ptr->value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> ptr = std::make_shared<myClass>();
    test(ptr);
    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
}
```

**output**

> ```
> Constructed 0.200000
> in test function
> 0.2
> finished
> Destructed 0.200000
> ```

Comment: Read about **in-class initializers** in your favorite [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Note also that even though `value` is `const`, it is not a compile time constant.

Comment: [Member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Comment: Refer to you code standard of choice when to prefer what: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-in-class-initializer

Comment: The first comment of the link in the question answers that this is possible in C++11.

Comment: The advice you are reading refers to older versions of C++ (or it's just inaccurate advice).

Comment: in-class intializers came much later into the language than the member initializer list, hence it is possible to find old and outdated material that says you can only initialize the const member in the member initializer list. New books do not necessarily mention that when they only refer to a newer standard

Comment: its a little odd to have this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495536/how-to-initialize-const-member-variable-in-a-class as dupe, because it also says one needs to use the member initializer list for the const member.