# Are member functions always inline, or is it just a hint?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

If we define a member function inside the class definition itself, is it necessarily treated inline or is it just a request to the compiler which it can ignore.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908830/isnt-cs-inline-totally-optional/910686#910686

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, functions that are defined inside a class body are implicitly `inline`.

(As with other functions declared `inline` it doesn't mean that the complier has to perform inline expansion in places where the function is called, it just enables the permitted relaxations of the "one definition rule", combined with the requirement that a definition must be included in all translation units where the function is used.)

Answer (score 5):

As stated by others, a method defined within a class is automatically requested inline.
It's useful to understand why.

Suppose it weren't.  You'd have to generate code for such a function, and everywhere it is called, a jump to subroutine instruction would have to reference the location, via the linker.

```
class A {
public:
  void f() { ... your code ... }
};
```

Every time this code is seen, if it's not inline, the compiler can only assume it must be generated, so it would generate a symbol.  Suppose it was like this:

A__f_v:

If that symbol were global, then if you happened to include this class code multiple times in different modules, you would have a multiply defined symbol error at link time.  So it can't be global.  Instead, it's file local.

Imagine you include the above header file in a number of modules.  In each one, it's going to generate a local copy of that code.  Which is better than not compiling at all, but you're getting multiple copies of the code when you really need only one.

This leads the the following conclusion: if your compiler is not going to inline a function, you are significantly better off declaring it somewhere once, and not requesting it to be inlined.

Unfortunately, what is and is not inline is not portable.  It's defined by the compiler writer.  A good rule of thumb is to always make every one liner, particularly all functions which themselves just call a function, inline, as you remove overhead.  Anything below three lines of linear code is almost certainly ok.  But if you have a loop in the code, the question is whether the compiler will allow it inline, and more to the point, how much benefit you would see even if it did what you want.

consider this inline code:

```
inline int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

It's not only almost as small as the prototype would be in source code, but the assembly language generated by the inline code is smaller than the call to a routine would be.  So this code is smaller, and faster.

And, if you happen to be passing in constants:

```
int c= add(5,4);
```

It's resolved at compile time and there is no code.

In gcc, I recently noticed that even if I don't inline code, if it's local to a file, they will sneakily inline it anyway.  It's only if I declare the function in a separate source module that they do not optimize away the call.

On the other end of the spectrum, suppose you request inline on a 1000 line piece of code.  Even if your compiler is silly enough to go along with it, the only thing you save is the call itself, and the cost is that every time you call it, the compiler must paste all that code in.  If you call that code n times, your code grows by the size of the routine * n.  So anything bigger than 10 lines is pretty much not worth inlining, except for the special case where it is only called a very small number of times.  An example of that might be in a private method called by only 2 others.

If you request to inline a method containing a loop, it only makes sense if it often executes a small number of times. But consider a loop which iterates one million times.  Even if the code is inlined, the percentage of time spent in the call is tiny.  So if you have methods with loops in it, which tend to be bigger anyway, those are worth removing from the header file because they a) will tend to be rejected as inline by the compiler and b) even if they were inlined, are generally not going to provide any benefit

Comment: You just blew my mind. If I define a function the normal way (with a definition over here and an implementation down there), and I put the keyword inline in front (of the implementation? definition? both?), then the compiler will consider inlining it? And this is better? My main concern with inline functions is that they are ugly and make the line long. Are you saying that I can have my normal sexy looking easy to read functions inline... and not only that, but that I _should_ mark small functions that way? I hope you are an active user and reply to this comment.

Comment: If you define a function using a prototype, with an implementation in the same header file marked inline, it will be made inline.  If your implementation is in another file, the compiler can't make it inline. It's not a mind reader, it doesn't know what code to generate.  I personally don't mind a little extra code in the header rather than writing it twice, but you certainly can do that if you prefer it.

Comment: @ziggy if I'm understanding your question right, yes, if your function is short, then defining it inline in the header file can be a huge runtime speed win, while slowing down compile time slightly and also requiring whatever symbols referenced in the inline function be defined.  This means that if your inline code refers to other objects, your header might have to include other headers.  So there is a potential big cost in recompilation time.  But for the average method (getter/setter, computing something with the private variables), inlining is a massive win.

Answer (score 3):

It is necessarily treated by the compiler as a request for inline -- which it can ignore. There are some idioms for defining some functions in the header (e.g. empty virtual destructors) and some necessary header definitions (template functions), but other than that see [GotW #33](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/033.htm) for more information.

Some have noted that the compiler may even inline functions you never asked it to, but I'm not sure whether that would defeat the purpose of requesting to inline a function.

Comment: Depends on the compiler.  In general, inline is a hint that doesn't do much.  I think most compilers targeted at embedded platforms listen to the hints more closely, and this is really the only space where you might outperform the compiler after careful design.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed inlined - but any inline request can be ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It is a request to the compiler that it can ignore.

Comment: No, it is a requirement. If a function is defined in a class body it must be treated as if it were declared `inline`.

Comment: like any `inline` request which the compiler can ignore.

Comment: Since it can be ignored, and most compilers will inline where appropriate even when you don't request it, it's a fairly useless hint.

Comment: @shoosh: Whether implicit or explicit, the compiler cannot ignore the rules for inline functions. For example, the fact that they may legitimately defined in multiple translation units.

Comment: @marr75: it's not useless; it allows you to define the function in more than one compilation unit, which is pretty much necessary for inlining it. It just doesn't do what you seem to want it to do (i.e. force the function to be inlined).

Comment: @Mike Seymour oops, overlooked that benefit, as you stated however, most people who ask this question are looking to force the function to be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

The 2003 ISO C++ standard says

> 7.1.2/2   A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.4) with an inline
>   specifier   declares an inline
>   function. The inline specifier
>   indicates to the   implementation that
>   inline substitution of the function
>   body at the   point of call is to be
>   preferred to the usual function call
>   mechanism. An implementation is not
>   required to perform this inline
>   substitution at the point of call;
>   however, even if this inline
>   substitution is omitted, the other
>   rules for inline functions   defined
>   by 7.1.2 shall still be respected.
>
> 7.1.2/3   A function defined within a class definition is an inline
>   function. The inline specifier shall
>   not appear on a block scope   function
>   declaration.
>
> 7.1.2/4   An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in
>   which it is used and shall have
>   exactly the same definition in every
>   case (3.2). [Note: a call to the
>   inline function may be encountered
>   before its defi-nition appears in the
>   translation unit. ] If a   function
>   with external linkage is declared
>   inline in one   transla-tion unit, it
>   shall be declared inline in all
>   translation   units in which it
>   appears; no diagnostic is required. An
>   inline   function with external
>   linkage shall have the same address in
>   all   translation units. A static
>   local variable in an extern inline
>   function always refers to the same
>   object. A string literal in an
>   extern inline function is the same
>   object in different translation
>   units.

Comment: This is the most useful answer, but is also misleading, in general, mainstream compilers focus on the "An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution" element of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that shouldn't be lumped together:

1. How you mark a function as being inline: define it with inline in front of the signature or define it at declaration point;
2. What the compiler will treat such inline marking: regardless of how you marked the function as inline it will be treated as a request by the compiler.